# jQuery dropdown menu exclude children from function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this

```
<div id="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="visiblestuff"></div>
    <div class="foldoutstuff">
        <form>
            <some input value/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the #dropdown-menu to be clickable but not it's children so I did this:

```
$(function() {
    var DropdownChildren = $('div#dropdown').children();
    $('div#dropdown').not(DropdownChildren).click(function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active');
        $('.foldoutstuff').toggle();
    });
});
```

This works for the background but not the form nodes...
I think the problem is caused by the toggle() on foldoutstuff

please advise

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to stop the event propagation from the children?

```
$(function() {
    $('div#dropdown').children().click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('div#dropdown').click(function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active');
        $('.foldoutstuff').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach to @Svetlin's answer (which requires less handlers to be bound), is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dropdown').bind('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target == this) { // Check it was this element clicked on; not a child
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.toggleClass('active');
            $('.foldoutstuff').toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

See the [`target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) attribute of the Event object

Comment: thanks, but what if the #dropdown has a child with some text in it.. which should be clickable

Comment: @Devon: Then you need to include that in your question, because it changes it completely!

Comment: Add another condition that checks if it has a certain class then. I.e if (e.target == this || $(this).hasClass('.visiblestuff')) { //... }

Comment: @Henry: You'll be comparing it to `e.target` rather than `this`. `this` will **always** be the `#dropdown` element.

Comment: @Matt Yeah I just noticed that, Hadnt checked it out. http://jsfiddle.net/JQcHN/1/ - I wont post this as a seperate answer as yours is correct this just includes that one change.